# Running and stopping a task on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, scheduled-tasks

I need to execute a batch file that run every minute for 1 minute. At the end of 1 minute it would execute another batch file which runs for 30 seconds.

It then repeats running the first batch file followed by the second. This would run indefinitely until stopped by the administrator. How do i achieve this on Windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

Why not make your 1st batch file call the 2nd batch file which then calls the first batch file and so on? The first batch file can be launched using Scheduled Tasks in Windows.

If you want to control the timing, write a program (e.g. C#) which will in a while loop run the batch files for the specified time in a separate thread.

**example C# console application:** (Known issue: Closing the console application does not stop the running batch file):

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace TimedBatchFile
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Close the console window to exit.");

                Process process1 = Process.Start("Notepad.exe");
                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
                process1.Kill();

                Process process2 = Process.Start("cmd.exe");
                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
                process2.Kill();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do i specify a duration within the batch file?

Comment: I am not sure. That is why I said you can use a C# application to do so.